# Referencing colum from JOIN in another JOINS subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm trying to write a little complicated POSTGRES query with joins, subqueries and agregate functions. All works fine but one thing. Here is the code:

```
SELECT 

table1.id AS id1,
table1.name AS name,
table1.table2_fkey AS id2
table2.name AS name2,
table2.id,
month_sum

FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.table2_fkey = table2.id) 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sum(months) AS month_sum FROM (
        SELECT (month_1 + month_2 + month_3 + month_4 + month_5 + month_6 + month_7 + month_8 + month_9 + month_10 + month_11 + month_12) as months FROM table2_places_years WHERE table2_places_fkey IN (
            SELECT id FROM table2_places WHERE table2_people_fkey IN (
                SELECT id FROM table2_people WHERE table2_fkey = table2.id
            )
        ) 
    ) AS months
) AS month_sum ON (table2.id = id2)
```

(i simplified the names of columns and tables)

Problem is that the last subquery in second JOIN doesn't have access to a table2 from the first join, so it throws an error. If i remove the where clause from last subquery, query runs fine, but gets me the sum of ALL rows in the 'table2_places_years'. I want the sum just from rows associated with current entry from table2 (linked with fkeys through another three tables).

Is there a way to 'let the subquery know' about columns from the first join clause?

Thanks in advance!

Note: this piece of code probably wouldn't work as i did some simplification.

Answer (score 1):

If the data allows it, rewrite the query using joins. It would then look like this:

```
join (
select table2_fkey, sum(…) …
from table2_places_years
join table2_places …
join table2_people …
group by table2_fkey
) month_sum on table2_fkey = table2.id
```

If it doesn't, you can also place the correlated subquery in the select statement:

```
select …,
      (
      select sum(…) …
      ) month_sum
from table1 left join table2 …
```

A last approach could be a lateral join. It might look like this:

```
SELECT 

table1.id AS id1,
table1.name AS name,
table1.table2_fkey AS id2
table2.name AS name2,
table2.id,
month_sum

FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.table2_fkey = table2.id),
LATERAL (
    SELECT sum(months) AS month_sum FROM (
        SELECT (month_1 + month_2 + month_3 + month_4 + month_5 + month_6 + month_7 + month_8 + month_9 + month_10 + month_11 + month_12) as months FROM table2_places_years WHERE table2_places_fkey IN (
            SELECT id FROM table2_places WHERE table2_people_fkey IN (
                SELECT id FROM table2_people WHERE table2_fkey = table2.id
            )
        ) 
    ) AS months
) month_sum
```

http://www.depesz.com/2012/08/19/waiting-for-9-3-implement-sql-standard-lateral-subqueries/

Comment: Thanks! I have to use postgres 8.4, so lateral join isn't an option (but thanks for a good tip on learning :-)), and actual data doesn't allow the first option, so the best choise would be the second one. I will study the correlated subqueries (didn't know about them till now) and post here a complete solution when i make it work. Thanks again!